# Передать параметры функции в другом порядке JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Как можно передать функции конкретные параметры? Гугл не помог, весьма странно, в других языках я такое встречал

```js
function test(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) {
  console.log('a', a, 'b', b, 'c', c);
}

test(c = 15); // мне нужно на выходе получить 1, 2, 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именованных параметров пока нет. Поэтому при вызове указать имя параметр нельзя.

Однако, в случае использования значений по умолчанию, они применяются если будет передано значение `undefined`, поэтому вызов может выглядеть так

```js
function test(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) {
  console.log('a', a, 'b', b, 'c', c);
}

test(undefined, undefined, 15); // мне нужно на выходе получить 1, 2, 15
```

Answer (score 4):

```js
function test(options) {
  options = Object.assign({a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}, options);
  console.log(options);
}

test({c: 15}); // мне нужно на выходе получить 1, 2, 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так мне кажется гораздо красивее и чуть короче :)

```js
function test({a = 1, b = 2, c = 3} = {})
{
    console.log(a, b, c);
}

test({c: 15});
```